# Xcode 10.2 Beta break point not working - The LLDB RPC server has crashed

Tags: xcode, breakpoints, xcode10.2

In Xcode 10.2 Beta -  Break point not working. Application removed from debugging mode and got terminal Message like below.

> Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log
>   is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix
>   'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash
>   log.

Any help appreciated.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Xcode 10.2 is no longer in beta. Are you using the latest, non-beta release of Xcode 10.2?

Comment: If you are getting this on the latest release of Xcode 10.2, then please do as Apple asks and file a bug report so they can fix the problem.

Comment: Hey Pratik, Do you get any fix for it?

Comment: @Mukesh Not any luck. But it's working on xCode10.2.